# CSS repeating header overlaps body text when printing

Tags: html, css

I have a header element that I want to repeat on every page when it prints. Currently it works as desired but when the body text flows to the next page it overlaps the header and so on. I have tried numerous things in the css messing with page breaks, display: block, adding a height to the header. I tried changing the position to something other than fixed but then the header doesn't display at the top of the page on every page.

```
header { 
    display: block;
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    right: 0px; 
}
```

I created a simple jsfiddle to show the code but it doesn't show my issue as I can't show it in print mode.
https://jsfiddle.net/v76p8qfm/

Here is a screenshot of the issue in print view:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your table HTML code?

Please, be sure that the `<table>` tag has no `<caption>` tag inside of it.

That worked for me.